# JProfiler on Centos 5.7 `GLIBC_2.7' not found

Tags: centos, glibc, jprofiler

JProfiler agent seems to require glibc 2.7, but Centos has glibc 2.5. Has anyone successfully compiled the jprofiler agent for glibc 2.5 or did previous version of JProfiler create agents with 2.5?

The actual error is:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> Could not find agent library /opt/jprofiler/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so in absolute path, with error: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /opt/jprofiler/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so)

Comment: Bad luck. Usually, `libc.so` is backward compatible, so you can install one from latest CentsOS version (make backups and make sure you system is not gonna break down).

Comment: Don't confuse GLib and glibc. They're two entirely different things. Retagging.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JProfiler you are using has been *built* on a system with glibc-2.7 (or later).

In general, UNIX systems support backwards compatibility (code compiled on an older system continues to work on a newer one), but not forward compatibility (you can't expect code built on a newer system to work on an older one).

Your choices are: upgrade your version of glibc, or obtain a different build of JProfiler (that was built on glibc-2.5 based system or older).

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a regression in 7.0.1, an easy workaround is to use 7.0:

http://download.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_linux_7_0.tar.gz

We'll fix this dependency problem shortly (my company develops JProfiler). Thanks for letting us know.